# VS Code Intellisense Icon is not displayed correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

My VS code:

```
Version: 1.57.0 (user setup)
Date: 2021-06-09T17:18:42.354Z
Electron: 12.0.9
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

It was coming like

[image]

For some reason i uninstalled and re-installed .. icons are not coming and all coming as abc. what is fix for this?
[image]

Comment: IntelliSense doesn't know what should be next. So it gave you a bunch of possible [words](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions).

Comment: i am looking proper icon for each like variable, method, class.. etc. instead all abc